# gcc debugging, Segmentation Fault (core dumped) but no core

Tags: c, debugging, gcc

It used to be that I would get `Segmentation Fault` with no core, then I added -ggdb to the compile command and executed this command in bash prior to executing gcc:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

All was good for a while (I got a core), but now I get `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` but no core in the directory where gcc command was issued?  Could it be going somewhere else?  What else can I try?

A little additional info:

1. OS: Gentoo Linux
2. Enable ELF core dumps is enabled in the running kernel.
3. The application is a text editor written in gtk+

**Answer:**
I found it two ways:

1. `find / -name "core" -ls`
2. As torek suggested:

   $ strace ./executable > output.txt 2>&1

   $ grep chdir output.txt

Comment: The core dump will be in the running process's current directory.  Does the process do `chdir()` at all?  If so, go where it goes.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, thanks for the suggestion.  The application is a text editor written in gtk+.  There isn't any chdir() in the source that I have written.  Just to be on the safe side (in case there is something in the gtk+ source) I ran it with only two tabs open, both files in the same dir (same as the executable), still no core.

Comment: The `core`(5) manual page explains how you can control if and when a `core` file is generated. Maybe the value in `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` points to a different directory (my sysadmin set ours up to generate uniquely named files in `/tmp`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @JonathanLeffler noted, the core dump goes in the current directory.

You can use `strace` to see if the process has done a chdir().  Unfortunately `strace` does not show where the core dump itself went, but:

```
$ cat crash.c
int main(void) {
    chdir("/tmp");
    *(int *)0 = 0;
    return 0;
}
$ cc -o crash crash.c
$ strace ./crash
execve("./crash", ["./crash"], [/* 53 vars */]) = 0
... [lots of libc trace stuff snipped] ...
chdir("/tmp")                           = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault
$ ls /tmp
```

and there is now a core.*pid* file in there.

Comment: thank you for you help as well.  I found the core in my home directory.  Using strace it showed that a chdir() was executed to my home dir.  I'll have to investigate that further. Thanks.